# Using Structs as keys in maps, ignoring == operators, false positive

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

I'm trying to use a struct as a key in a map, but despite defining `<` and `==` operators I'm getting false positives:

`return models[mr];` is returning even when the new `ImportSettings` has `reverse = true` and the one in models has `reverse = false.

The Visual studio debugger also shows that the operator calls for `==` aren't even being called. What have I misunderstood here?

```
struct HE2_ImportSettings
{
    bool reverseWindingOrder = false;

    bool operator==(const HE2_ImportSettings& other)const
    {
        return reverseWindingOrder == other.reverseWindingOrder;
    }
};

struct ModelReference
{
    std::string filepath = "";
    HE2_ImportSettings importSettings = {};

    bool ModelReference::operator == (const ModelReference& other) const
    {
        return filepath == other.filepath && importSettings == other.importSettings;
    }
    bool ModelReference::operator< (const ModelReference& other) const
    {
        return filepath < other.filepath;
    }
};



ModelReference mr = { filename, importSettings };

bool exists = models.count(mr);
if (exists)
{
    //This is returning even when the new importsettings has reverse = true and the one in models has reverse = false
    return models[mr];
}
```

Comment: what are "false positives" ?

Comment: `std::map` never calls `operator ==`, only `operator <`.  If you need help fixing your code, please post a [mre]

Comment: To both above - The bottom of my code has a MRE. There's comment explaining it and it's been there since I posted, it's not editted in. Those voting to close this question - The answer solves my problem and could help others, it really shouldn't be closed for that reason

Comment: @WillHain It helps to put explanations in the prose, not (only) in the code. Not everyone will read all the way through the code to discover that you explain the behaviour there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` uses the concept of equivalence. Two elements are equivalent when

```
!(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

In other words, a map never uses `==` to see if two elements are the same. In your map two elements are considered equivalent when they have the same `filepath`. If you want to take also `importSettings` into account for the ordering in the map you need to compare that also in the `operator<`.